# Database Access Replication in Microservices

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rabbitmq

I am new to Microservices and I am trying to learn and embrace it.

Right now I have two services and the message broker is RabbitMQ.

My database of choice is MongoDB.

My question now is, is it advised to allow all the services to open a connection to my MongoDB database or should I allow only one service(DatabaseService) to open a connection to the database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming the two services should indeed be two separate services (ie are separated/isolated as far as their bounded context, schemas, etc.) and not one then ideally they should each connect to the database and not go through an intermediate DatabaseService dependency.